# How to rotate android switch widget by 90°

Tags: java, android, rotation, switch-statement

I'm trying to rotate the backported switch by BoD (https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) by 90°. I played with the class Switch, and I finally managed to make it look OK (http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/8662/oslz.jpg). However, it doesn't work properly. If i try to toggle the button, it gets painted somewhere below the view, so I see just a part of it.

I edited methods onMeasure() and onDraw() in the original Switch by BoD:

```
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);


    if (mOnLayout == null) {
        mOnLayout = makeLayout(mTextOn);
    }
    if (mOffLayout == null) {
        mOffLayout = makeLayout(mTextOff);
    }

    mTrackDrawable.getPadding(mTempRect);
    final int maxTextWidth = Math.max(mOnLayout.getWidth(), mOffLayout.getWidth());
    final int switchWidth = Math.max(mSwitchMinWidth, maxTextWidth * 2 + mThumbTextPadding * 4 +  
    mTempRect.left+ mTempRect.right);              
    final int switchHeight = mTrackDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

    mThumbWidth = maxTextWidth + mThumbTextPadding * 2;

    switch (widthMode) {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            widthSize = Math.min(widthSize, switchWidth);
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            widthSize = switchWidth;
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            // Just use what we were given
            break;
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            heightSize = Math.min(heightSize, switchHeight);
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            heightSize = switchHeight;
            break;

        case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            // Just use what we were given
            break;
    }
```

Here comes the edited code - I replaced this block:

```
    mSwitchWidth = switchWidth;
    mSwitchHeight = switchHeight

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (measuredHeight < switchHeight) {
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), switchHeight);
    }
    }
```

with this:

```
    mSwitchWidth = switchHeight;
    mSwitchHeight = switchWidth;

    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    final int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    if (measuredWidth < switchWidth) {
        //setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidthAndState(), switchHeight);
        setMeasuredDimension(switchHeight, switchWidth);
    }    
    }
```

And I added these 2 lines to the onDraw() method:

```
    canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
    canvas.rotate(90);
```

I uploaded the original code of Switch by BoD here: http:// pastebin.com/8CU9ybET
I'm also wondering, the mSwitchWidth and mSwitchHeight are used in onLayout() method, so maybe I should tweak it somehow too... Thank you for any ideas ppl ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it as follows;

First, place a file in /res/anim/ called rotation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="0" android:fillAfter="true">
</rotate>
```

Then, in your Activity's onCreate, do

```
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);

     Animation rotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
     LayoutAnimationController animController = new LayoutAnimationController(rotateAnim, 0);
     FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyScreen_ContentLayout);
     layout.setLayoutAnimation(animController);
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Now the toggling works properly, I never wished it could be that simple... However, now I see only a half height of the switch, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: If the answer, helped, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer.

Comment: It helped m8, and I'll definitely accept your answer if we make it work 100% - but as i said, only half of the button height is showing now :/

Comment: You will have to adjust the height and the width according to the screen layout. They are different fro Vertical and Horizontal Screen. Hope that helps.

Comment: And can I get the height of my rotated switch somehow? So that I could set the new height programatically?

Comment: Now I noticed a weird thing - if i drag the button with my finger, I have to drag it over the whole screen to make the switch thumb move to the end :S If I drag it only inside the switch, it barely moves at all

Comment: Change the layout from wrapcontent to android:layout_width="180px" android:layout_height="10px" in your XML file

Comment: Also, go through this link for more details. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html

Comment: Now the switch looks cool, but the handling is not great - the horizontal switch responds perfectly, but this one needs me to drag my finger really far to toggle it :/ over the whole screen actually

Comment: You will need to edit the question or place a new question. Am glad the above solutions worked for you to get some important stuff done. You would have to do some more work and then ask a question. :)

Comment: Well I don't know what more work to do on that now... But you're right, the main idea was achieved, I'll create a new question ;)

Answer (score 3):

After 4 years someone might find this answer useful.
the whole heck of rotation of a **View** can be handled by adding a just a single line to xml file of that view like:

```
<View
    android:rotation="90"
    ... />
```